# link to page_for_posts

Tags: php, posts, javascript

Trying to create a button that leads to the blog from my static homepage.
As i understand it there is a function called get option page_for_posts that seems suitable for this.
But when i try to pass it through to my button nothing happens, what am i missing here?

```
<input type="button" class="cta-button" value="Newsfeed" onclick="window.open('<?php get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); ?>', '_self')">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't classify this as a WordPress issue persay. The problem is that any `get_*()` functions return values. This means that [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) returns the permalink to be assigned ot a variable which you're not doing or intend to do in this case. So we have the value sitting in memory all we need to do is print / [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) it:

```
echo get_permalink( $post_id );
```

Or in your case:

```
<input type="button" class="cta-button" value="Newsfeed" onclick="window.open('<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); ?>', '_self')">
```